# Xib, Label text Change

Tags: swift, label, xib

How do I work with a Label that hangs on a xib?

```
lblName.text = "Label Text"
```

I am getting error associated with

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image] 
[image: Image2]

Comment: Where you getting error?

Comment: you need to link xib with swift file, then link each textbox with appropriate textbox...

Comment: Can a simple example?
My example
https://yadi.sk/d/dO2cS3As3JDBEZ

Answer (score 1):

You should update your custom `View` class in the following way.

First of all, open `View.xib` file set `File's Owner` custom class to `View` like the image in given below

[image]

after set `UILabel` IBOutlets like the image given below

[image]

After that open View.swift file and paste the code given below

```
class View: UIView {

    private var view: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var firstname: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    //FIXME:- Set up
    func xibSetup() {

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }





}
```

Now you can variable of `View` class in `ViewController`.

Comment: Error: let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIViewenter image description here